# MySQL fetches 2 of each database row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, left-join

I can't quite figure out why, but my code generates 2 of each database row to my table.

This is my SELECT statement

```
//select all data
$query = "SELECT e.employeeid, e.name, e.title, e.phone, s.name as supplier_name, e.created 
            FROM employeestest e 
                LEFT JOIN supplierstest s 
                    ON s.supplierid 
            ORDER BY e.employeeid DESC
            LIMIT :from_record_num, :records_per_page";

$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":from_record_num", $from_record_num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":records_per_page", $records_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

//number of rows returned
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
```

This is where I populate the table (There are headers before this, that's why thee is no start table tag)

```
// retrieve table contents
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    extract($row);

    //creating new table row per record
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='text-align-center'><input type='checkbox' name='item[]' class='checkboxes' value='{$employeeid}' /></td>";
        echo "<td>{$name}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$title}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$phone}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$supplier_name}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$created}</td>";
        echo "<td>";

            // update record
            echo "<a href='update_product.php?employeeid={$employeeid}' class='btn btn-info margin-right-1em'>";
                echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Rediger";
            echo "</a>";

            // delete record
            echo "<a delete-employeeid='{$employeeid}' delete-file='delete_product.php' class='btn btn-danger delete-object'>";
                echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Slet";
            echo "</a>";

        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
//end table<br>
echo "</table>";
```

Let me know if more code is needed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `join` condition is wrong.  You need a condition.  Something like this:

```
        FROM employeestest e LEFT JOIN
             supplierstest s 
             ON s.supplierid = e.supplierid
-----------------------------^
```

Or whatever the appropriate column is for linking the two tables.

Comment: That did the job! 
Also makes sense when I see the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
use like this: 

$query = "SELECT e.employeeid, e.name, e.title, e.phone, s.name as supplier_name, e.created 
        FROM employeestest e 
            LEFT JOIN supplierstest s 
                ON s.supplierid = e.supplierid  
        ORDER BY e.employeeid DESC
        LIMIT :from_record_num, :records_per_page";
```

-- e.supplierid or e.suppliedcoumnname whatever it is.